# Exchanging icons in listview items

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change icon image according to the item data . when pressing the icon, it should switch to other icon and change the item data. everything is going right but when i scroll up or down the new icon image change its place to some other items because i am using list view with adapter. how can i keep the new icons in the pressed items without mixing with other items.

```
package com.example.sairamkrishna.handymade;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HandAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HandClass> {
    private int myColor;

    public HandAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HandClass> objects, int my_Color) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        myColor = my_Color;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View myView = convertView;
        final HandClass myData = getItem(position);

        if (myView == null) {
            myView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.label_item, parent, false);

        }

        ImageView aImage = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
        aImage.setImageResource(myData.getClsImage());

        TextView aName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        aName.setText(myData.getClsName());

        FrameLayout aColor = (FrameLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.itemColor);
        aColor.setBackgroundColor(myColor);

        final ImageView aAddToBasket = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.itemAddToBasket);
        aAddToBasket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Boolean aClsToBasket = (Boolean) myData.getClsToBasket();

                if (aClsToBasket) {
                    aAddToBasket.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_circle);
                    myData.setClsToBasket(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Remove from basket"+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    // if (!aClsToBasket) {
                    aAddToBasket.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove_circle);
                    myData.setClsToBasket(true);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Add to basket"+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        ImageView aAddToFavorite = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.itemAddToFavorite);
        aAddToFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Favorite - List item was clicked at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return myView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A fundamental concept of ListView and RecyclerView is that you need to "update" the value (in this case, the image) for each portion of the row **every** time `getView()` or `onBindViewHolder()` is called.

For example, every time `getView()` is called, you're always updating the (text) value of `TextView aName`. That is, there is *always* a call to `aName.setText()`.

Right now, the only time you call `aAddToBasket.setImageResource()` is inside an `OnClickListener`. Of course, it makes sense to do it here, but you must  *also* update the image outside of the listener.

Add this code right after your `ImageView aAddToBasket` line:

```
if ((Boolean) myData.getClsToBasket()) {
    aAddToBasket.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove_circle);
} else {
    aAddToBasket.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_circle);
}
```

Comment: I've kept your cast to `Boolean` because I don't know exactly how your data is structured, but there's a chance it's already a `boolean` and then the cast is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after icon change.

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`